# Sanitize JS scripts inside script tag of html file on ruby

Tags: html, ruby

I try extracting contents from html file using Ruby (not RoR)

I was doing this:

```
require 'sanitize'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html_document)
a = Sanitize.fragment(doc.css('body'))
```

This extract contents inside the `<body>` tag, and remove all html tags. But, unfortunately, JS scripts still remain which existed inside `<script>` tag.

How do I remove JS scripts in addition to html tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your are using the newest version of [Sanitize](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize).

```
html = "<html><head><title></title><style>.red{color:red;}</style></head><body><div>... <b>some content</b> ...</div><script>... a script ...</script></body></html>"

Sanitize.fragment(html, :remove_contents => ['script'])
# => ".red{color:red;} ... some content ... "

Sanitize.fragment(html, :remove_contents => ['script', 'style'])
# => " ... some content ... "
```

Please see: [:remove_contents](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize#remove_contents-boolean-or-array-or-set)